# Referring to the value part of Ansible inventory entry

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

If I have a following entry in my Ansible `hosts` file:

```
[dbserver]
myserver
```

Then elsewhere in my task code I can refer to `myserver` as `{{ groups['dbserver'][0] }}` to get the hostname dynamically. Works great.

Now - similar scenario. Say I changed the `hosts` file to:

```
[dbserver]
db1 ansible_host=myserver ansible_user=myuser
```

What I found out that `{{ groups['dbserver'][0] }}` will now return "db1" and it seems to be a plain string. But what if I need to refer to both the actual hostname "myserver" and also need to know the user "myuser". How do I access these values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ansible_host` and `ansible_user` are defined for a specific hosts, so they are accessible with `hostvars`:

```
- debug:
    var: hostvars['db1']['ansible_host']
- debug:
    var: hostvars['db1']['ansible_user']
```

Comment: Fantastic! Exactly the answer I've been looking for!